# ¿es posible saber qué nodo está respondiendo a una query en Galera cluster?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tenemos montado un cluster de mariadb con Galera con 3 nodos.
Tenemos un balaceandor por delante ProxySQL, con 2 máquinas con keeaplived una en modo master y otra en modo slave.
El cliente piensa tener bases de datos grandes, en las que va a hacer muchas peticiones tanto consultas como insercciones. Quiere saber si va a tener un buen rendimiento con este cluster y para saber como organizar los nodos (unos nodos como escritura y otros como lectura-escritura) quiere hacer pruebas de inserciones y consultas y en esas peticiones, saber qué nodo le está respondiendo en ese momento. Al tenerlo balanceado con ProxySQL, ¿hay manera de saber mediante la consulta inicial qué nodo es el que responde?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! interesante pregunta :)

Comment: Vea [Official ProxySQL Documentation :: Query Logging](https://proxysql.com/Documentation/Query-Logging/).

Answer (score 0):

En tu link, prueba ejecutar `crm resource status` y te va a indicar cuál nodo está activo.

Ejemplo:

```
Master/Slave Set:....
     Masters: [ mysql-1 ]
     Slaves: [ mysql-2 ]
```